# (FPDF, PHP, SQL) table values after first page gets messy

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I am using PHP and fPDF to create a PDF "invoice" and everything works perfectly fine on the first page but when the table has to go to the second page it only returns the first value from the sql query and everything goes to the rest goes to the third page and so on.

[image: pdf image]

This is the code that loops the table rows

```
  $sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM rostosativos_invoice where id_proposta = '".$_GET['id']."';");
  $res=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        // produto = posição 5
        // quantidade = posição 7
        // precouni = posição 6
        // soma = posição 9

        //multicell 
        $cellWidth=120;//tamanho da cell
        $cellHeight=6.5;//altura da cell

        //verificar se o texto passa a cell
        if($pdf->GetStringWidth($r['produto']) < $cellWidth){
              //se não, não fazer nada
              $line=1;
        }else{
              //~se estiver, ~então calcular a altura necessária para a cobrir a cell
              //ao dividir o texto para ajustar ao tamanho da cell
              //~depois contar quantas linhas são necessãrias para ajustar o texto na cell

              $textLength=strlen($r['produto']); //total text length
              $errMargin=10;          //cell com margem de erro, just in case
              $startChar=0;           //posição inicial para cada linha
              $maxChar=0;             //Máxima caracteres numa linha, para incremetar mais tarde
              $textArray=array();     //Guardar as strings em cada linha
              $tmpString="";          //Guardar a string numa linha temporária

              while($startChar < $textLength){ //loop até ao fim do texto
                    //loop até chegar ao máximo de caracteres
                    while( 
                    $pdf->GetStringWidth( $tmpString ) < ($cellWidth-$errMargin) &&
                    ($startChar+$maxChar) < $textLength ) {
                          $maxChar++;
                          $tmpString=substr($r['produto'],$startChar,$maxChar);
                    }
                    //mover startChar para a próxima linha
                    $startChar=$startChar+$maxChar;
                    //depois adicionar para o array para saber quantas linhas serão necessárias
                    array_push($textArray,$tmpString);
                    //reset maxChar e tmpString
                    $maxChar=0;
                    $tmpString='';

              }
              //receber o numero de linhas
              $line=count($textArray);
        }

        //usar MultiCell em vez de Cell
        //mas primeiro, como a MultiCell é sempre tratada como fim de linha, precisamos de 
        //definir manualmente a posição xy para a próxima cell ficar ao lado.
        //guardar a posição x e y antes de escrever a multicell
        $xPos=$pdf->GetX();
        $yPos=$pdf->GetY();
        $pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,$r['produto'],1,'L');
        //receber a posição para a próxima cell ao lado da multicell
        //e equilibrar o x com o tamanho da multicell
        $pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);
        //escrever as cells
        $pdf->Cell(15,($line * $cellHeight),$r['quantidade'],1,0); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas
        $pdf->Cell(10,($line * $cellHeight),'UNI',1,0); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas

        $pdf->Cell(25,($line * $cellHeight),$r['precouni'].chr(128),1,0); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas
        $pdf->Cell(25,($line * $cellHeight),$r['soma'].chr(128),1,1); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas
  }
```

This is the full PHP code:

```
  class PDF extends TFPDF {
  // Page Header

      function Header() {
        require("../config.php");
        $rows = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM rostosativos_invoice INNER JOIN rostosativos_empresas ON rostosativos_invoice.empresa = rostosativos_empresas.empresa where id_proposta ='".$_GET['id']."';");
        $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows);
        $id_empresa = $r['id_empresa'];
        $idproposta = $r['id_proposta'];
        $responsavel = $r['responsavel'];
        $empresa = $r['empresa'];
        $data = $r['data_registo'];
        $contribuinte = $r['contribuinte'];
        $assunto = $r['assunto'];
        $refcliente = $r['refcliente'];
        // Logo
        $this->SetY(4);
        $this->Image('../logo.png',10,6,30);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(90);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(100,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Sede: Rua Azenha dos Latoeiros, 1-A || 2580-557 Ribafria  '),'LTR',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(90);
        $this->Cell(100,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Oficina: Estrada Nacional nº1 km 33.3'),'LR',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(90);
        $this->Cell(100,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Quinta do Chacão, Casal Machado 2580-364 Alenquer '),'LR',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(90);
        $this->Cell(100,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','E-mail: geral@rostosativos.com'),'LR',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(90);
        $this->Cell(100,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','www.rostosativos.com'),'LR',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);
        $this->Cell(90);
        $this->Cell(100,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','www.facebook.com/rostosativos/'),'LBR',0,'C');
        // Line break

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);

        $this->Ln(15);

        $this->Cell(100 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(35 ,5,'Proposta: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(34 ,5, $idproposta,0,1);//end of line

        $this->Cell(100 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(35 ,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Ref. Cliente: '),0,0);
        $this->Cell(34 ,5,$refcliente,0,1);//end of line

        $this->Cell(100 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(35 ,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','N.º Contribuinte: '),0,0);
        $this->Cell(34 ,5,$contribuinte,0,1);//end of line

        $this->Cell(100 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(35 ,5,'Data: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(34 ,5,$data,0,1);//end of line

        $this->Ln(5);

        //billing address
        $this->Cell(100 ,5,'Proposta para:',0,0);//end of line
        $this->Cell(100 ,5,'Assunto da proposta:',0,1);//end of line

        //add dummy cell at beginning of each line for indentation
        $this->Cell(10 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(90 ,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$empresa),0,0);

        $this->Cell(10 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(90 ,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$assunto),0,1);

        $this->Cell(10 ,5,'',0,0);
        $this->Cell(90 ,5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$responsavel),0,1);

        $this->Ln(2);
        //invoice contents
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

        $this->Cell(120 ,6.5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Designação'),1,0);
        $this->Cell(15 ,6.5,'Qtd.',1,0);
        $this->Cell(10 ,6.5,'UNI',1,0);
        $this->Cell(25, 6.5,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Preço UNI.'),1,0);
        $this->Cell(25 ,6.5,'Total',1,1);//end of line

      }

      function Footer() {
        require("../config.php");
        //~Tabela de Preço, etc..
        $this->SetY(-20);
        $sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM rostosativos_invoice where id_proposta = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
        $res=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

              $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
              $this->Cell(30, 6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Exclusões:'),0,0);
              $this->Cell(15);
              $this->Cell(65 ,6,'',0,0);
              $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
              $this->Cell(40 ,6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Soma'),0,0);
              $this->Cell(15);
              $this->Cell(30, 6, $r['totalsoma'].chr(128),1,1,'R');

              $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
              $this->Cell(30,6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['exclusao1']),0, 'L');
              $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
              $this->Cell(15);
              $this->Cell(65 ,6,'',0,0);
              $this->Cell(40 ,6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Mão de Obra'),0,0);
              $this->Cell(15);
              $this->Cell(30, 6, $r['maoobra'].chr(128),1,1,'R');

              $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
              $this->Cell(30,6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$r['exclusao2']),0, 'L');
              $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
              $this->Cell(80 ,6,'',0,0);
              $this->Cell(40 ,6,'Valor GLOBAL em EUROS',0,0);
              $this->Cell(15);
              $this->Cell(30 ,6,$r['precototal'].chr(128),1,1,'R');//end of line  
        }
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-9);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252','Página '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}'),0,0,'C');
      }
  }
  //A4 width : 219mm
  //default margin : 10mm each side
  //writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

  //create pdf object

  $pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
  $pdf -> AliasNbPages();
  //add new page
  $pdf->AddPage();
  // Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
  $pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
  $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',12);
  //set font to arial, regular, 12pt
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

  $sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM rostosativos_invoice where id_proposta = '".$_GET['id']."';");
  $res=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        // produto = posição 5
        // quantidade = posição 7
        // precouni = posição 6
        // soma = posição 9

        //multicell 
        $cellWidth=120;//tamanho da cell
        $cellHeight=6.5;//altura da cell

        //verificar se o texto passa a cell
        if($pdf->GetStringWidth($r['produto']) < $cellWidth){
              //se não, não fazer nada
              $line=1;
        }else{
              //~se estiver, ~então calcular a altura necessária para a cobrir a cell
              //ao dividir o texto para ajustar ao tamanho da cell
              //~depois contar quantas linhas são necessãrias para ajustar o texto na cell

              $textLength=strlen($r['produto']); //total text length
              $errMargin=10;          //cell com margem de erro, just in case
              $startChar=0;           //posição inicial para cada linha
              $maxChar=0;             //Máxima caracteres numa linha, para incremetar mais tarde
              $textArray=array();     //Guardar as strings em cada linha
              $tmpString="";          //Guardar a string numa linha temporária

              while($startChar < $textLength){ //loop até ao fim do texto
                    //loop até chegar ao máximo de caracteres
                    while( 
                    $pdf->GetStringWidth( $tmpString ) < ($cellWidth-$errMargin) &&
                    ($startChar+$maxChar) < $textLength ) {
                          $maxChar++;
                          $tmpString=substr($r['produto'],$startChar,$maxChar);
                    }
                    //mover startChar para a próxima linha
                    $startChar=$startChar+$maxChar;
                    //depois adicionar para o array para saber quantas linhas serão necessárias
                    array_push($textArray,$tmpString);
                    //reset maxChar e tmpString
                    $maxChar=0;
                    $tmpString='';

              }
              //receber o numero de linhas
              $line=count($textArray);
        }

        //usar MultiCell em vez de Cell
        //mas primeiro, como a MultiCell é sempre tratada como fim de linha, precisamos de 
        //definir manualmente a posição xy para a próxima cell ficar ao lado.
        //guardar a posição x e y antes de escrever a multicell
        $xPos=$pdf->GetX();
        $yPos=$pdf->GetY();
        $pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,$r['produto'],1,'L');
        //receber a posição para a próxima cell ao lado da multicell
        //e equilibrar o x com o tamanho da multicell
        $pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);
        //escrever as cells
        $pdf->Cell(15,($line * $cellHeight),$r['quantidade'],1,0); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas
        $pdf->Cell(10,($line * $cellHeight),'UNI',1,0); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas

        $pdf->Cell(25,($line * $cellHeight),$r['precouni'].chr(128),1,0); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas
        $pdf->Cell(25,($line * $cellHeight),$r['soma'].chr(128),1,1); //adaptar a altura ao número de linhas
  }




  //output the result
  $pdf->Output();

  $content = $pdf->Output('propostas/'.$_GET['id'].'.pdf','F');
  file_put_contents($content);
```

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Does it only happen on the 2nd page or does it also happen on page 4 etc?

Comment: @Dave It happens everytime it turns to another page check the image in the beginning of the post please

Comment: @NicoHaase I haven't tried much I only checked the cells size, I tried to understand what is causing the problem but it seems everything is ok I'm trying to solve this for hours it looks like it doesn't have a solution, I'm a beginner in fpdf by the way

Comment: Your image only shows 3 pages which is why I asked if it happens again on the 4th page. I don't see anything in your code that should cause what you are seeing to happen. I suspect that it is in the calculations you are doing when a cell has multiple lines but I don't read Spanish so I'm not sure what the comments say. This line in particular seems suspect `$pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);`. I think it may be setting your `Y` location incorrectly and forcing a new page when it shouldn't be.

Comment: What happens if product 25 is NOT long enough to need more than one line (like product 24)?

Comment: @Dave I think the same ! but I don't understand what is missing or causing that bug I'll leave a print with the other pages and the comments with english language http://prntscr.com/nd7lgy  http://prntscr.com/nd7mdr

Comment: I just noticed the other 2 images you posted with the English comments so let me go look at that. Thanks for that and the other 2 pages which show it isn't related to the length of the product name.

Comment: Try changing `$pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,$r['produto'],1,'L');` to `$pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,($line * $cellHeight),$r['produto'],1,'L');`. You changed the height of the other columns but not the column with the description. That is probably what is causing another new page to be generated.

Comment: [this](http://prntscr.com/nda3h9) is the result, I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utjJe90MeEw) tutorial on the internet and I adapted to the table that I already had (the source code link is in the description), still not working :'(

Comment: Remove my suggestion since it obviously didn't work. You/we need to see what the positioning is being set to as things are being output. Right after `$pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);` add `echo $xPos . '*' . $cellWidth . '*' . $yPos . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;`. This will break your PDF being created but it will show the positioning values which seem to be the root of the problem.

Comment: [this](http://prntscr.com/ndalbx) is the output, which value am I supposed to look for ? (this is edited because I deleted this line `$pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);`)

Comment: OK, this isn't a problem with your code per se, it's a problem with how the tutorial you were following is doing things. Using his example and causing it to flow over to multiple pages shows the same problem that you are having. He doesn't take into consideration having headers or footers. It's going to take me a little bit of time to figure out a solution and it might not be until tomorrow.

Comment: @Dave take your time, I have time to do this I'm developing another page at the moment so tomorrow I'll check if you post something, thanks for your time Dave I appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make these changes right after you define the PDF and pages.

```
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf -> AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);  // add this line and the next
$howhigh = $pdf->GetPageHeight();  // stash the height of the page for later
```

The next change is in the `else` where the size of the larger cells is calculated. There is really no reason to go through the data to be added character by character. You can replace that block of code with:

```
//verificar se o texto passa a cell
if ($pdf->GetStringWidth($r['produto']) < $cellWidth) {
    //se não, não fazer nada
    $line=1;
} else {
        $line = ceil($pdf->GetStringWidth($item[2]));
        $line = round($line / $cellWidth,0) + 1;
}
```

Finally, the actual output of the data needs a little change to account for testing whether or not we need to start a new page. As you'll see the calculation done above are used.

```
//usar MultiCell em vez de Cell
//mas primeiro, como a MultiCell é sempre tratada como fim de linha, precisamos de 
//definir manualmente a posição xy para a próxima cell ficar ao lado.
//guardar a posição x e y antes de escrever a multicell
$xPos=$pdf->GetX();
$yPos=$pdf->GetY();
$total = $yPos + (($line * $cellHeight));
if ($total > $howhigh) {  // we will spill to a new page with this cell
    $pdf->AddPage();      // so start a new page before we add the cell
    $xPos=$pdf->GetX();
    $yPos=$pdf->GetY();
}
$pdf->MultiCell($cellWidth,$cellHeight,$r['produto'],1,'L');
//receber a posição para a próxima cell ao lado da multicell
//e equilibrar o x com o tamanho da multicell
$pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth , $yPos);
```

Comment: It's returning this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDF::GetPageHeight()`   I made the changes you said , the error line it's this one `$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
      $pdf -> AliasNbPages();
      $pdf->AddPage();
      $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);  // add this line and the next
      $howhigh = $pdf->GetPageHeight();  // stash the height of the page for later`

Comment: I changed `$howhigh = $pdf->GetPageHeight();` to `$howhigh = $pdf-> h;` and it worked, but I had to change the if statement to `if ($total > $howhigh - 25)` because If the if statement is like this `if ($total > $howhigh)` It overwrittes the footer. but now I have this little problem in one multicell [image](http://prntscr.com/ndk2c7) in "artigo25" it has a little space, how can I fix that ?

Comment: Try putting your line height logic back in the `else` statement and see if that corrects it. I can't duplicate what you have exactly so it's hard to test the same way you are able to.

Comment: If the call to `GetPageHeight` failed what version of fPDF are you using? It should have worked if you're using the latest version.

Comment: I'm using FPDF 1.81 and TFPDF as well so I can use € symbol  ,,, what do you mean by putting line height logic back in the else statement ? Right now I have this [img](http://prntscr.com/ndmggm)

Comment: Never mind trying that it won't help. The problem is the imprecise measuring and calculating of the cell size when the long lines need to be wrapped. Still looking at it.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892161/5260982) to a similar problem. This is a non-trivial problem to solve though that answer does provide a solution.

Comment: Okay I used that function and it just makes the height even bigger, now I'm using the code you posted yesterday here and I refreshed the "artigo25AAAAA..." to "artigo25aaaaa..." and works fine but if I change to "artigo25AAAA..." again it gets that height bug again (????)  sometimes my mind just explode in situations like these...

Comment: I just can't understand what's happening here , take a look at these prints please (it looks like it doesn't allow me to use "A" and "a" at the same time) [print](http://prntscr.com/ndn22l)

Comment: It is all a matter of the height of the actual characters which depends on the font and the size of the font. The best you can do it seems is calculate the closest number of lines required to contain the text. Depending on the mix of characters in the text the actual height might be off once in a while. Since you have been testing with test data so far what happens with real data? I suspect that in almost all cases it will be fine with a minor number of edge cases that will have the wrapped text cell slightly smaller than it needs to be.

Comment: I've put real data on that line and this is the output [print](http://prntscr.com/ndngj1) I think I'm going to forget this problem because I don't know what to do

Comment: Well that output looks OK.

Comment: Yes it does, but I'm just afraid when they start using the program this just bugs everything because it's my first time .

Comment: For what it's worth the minor hiccup that may show up is quite likely to never be noticed unless it is pointed out. Ultimately though it is up to you of course.

Comment: Yes true ahahah, but at least this is working fine for now. Thank you for all the help and time @Dave !

Comment: one more thing, I used this code you sended me before `echo $line . '*' . $cellHeight .'<br />' . PHP_EOL;` and I figured out that when it reaches the second line / middle line (in multicell) it adds one more line to the `$line` and thats why the next cell height is much bigger than the description cell

Comment: remember the problem that I had with the cell width ? I went to it again and I fixed it ! all I had to do was this [link](http://prntscr.com/njvm4d) uff ahah

Comment: Nice job! Thanks for posting a resolution.